# Анимация смены вьюх UIViewContainerController`а, как в PageController`e

Tags: objective-c, анимация, controller, ios7

У меня есть MainViewController. Он выступает в роли контейнер-контроллера. На него по очереди (в зависимости от нажатой кнопки) добавляются другие вьюконтроллеры (меньшего размера). Т.е. первый (который стоит по умолчанию) ремувится, второй добаляется как child. Добавил Swipe Gesture. Возможно ли анимировать добавление и ремув контроллеров наподобие, как в PageViewController? Сам по себе PageViewController для поставленой задачи не подходит (к сожалению).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так если MainViewController кастомный, значит и childs добавляются в своем же коде? 
Значит, вы можете просто применить любую анимацию к view этих UIViewController'ов при добавлении и удалении. То есть взять, например, не swipe, в UIPanGestureRecognizer, получать информацию, где сейчас палец пользователя, и вести view за ним. Ну или по свайпу запускать анимацию смены вьюх через `[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:compeltion:]`.